# Background image transition on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have html page and I set background image in css rule:

```
body{ background-image:url("/someurl");}
```

And i have button, when i hover it I'm change background image. But i do it using JQuery like this

`body.css('background-image', 'url(' + initialimageSrc + ')');`

I 'd like to have a transition on backgound-image change, but when I use

```
transition:background-image 2s linear;
```

It looks very bad. Can any one help?

Comment: have you tried  ease-in-out instead of linear ?

Comment: @WarrenGrimskin, it`s also works very bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, actually, this way of transitioning a background-image only supports fade-in, fade-out, and doesn't really offer any customisability.
my advice is to create a second object, which will fade in and out alternatively.

try to follow the conventions in http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/ - it helped me a lot with that subject.

Comment: Thanks, I watched at this examples. But I hope that exists some approach which doesn't need absolute positioning images.

Comment: well, if you think it through, it's impossible. sorry.